# Checking if guessed string has a correct character at the wrong position

Tags: c++

I want to generate a random string with letters a,b,c,d then let the user guess it. 
My output should be which positions the user guessed correctly and how many letters the user guessed correctly but put them in the wrong position.

Current attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char lettres[4] =
    {
        'a',
        'b',
        'c',
        'd'
    };
    char rString[4];
    int i = 0;

    srand(time(0));

    while (i < 4) 
    {
        int temp = rand() % 4;
        rString[i] = lettres[temp];
        i++;
    }

    int u = 0;
    char t[4];

    while (u < 10)
    {
        cout << "Enter your guess:\n ";
        cin >> t;

        for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++)
        {
             cout << rString[z] << ", "; //printing random string
        }
        cout << "\n";

        int k;
        int compteur = 0;
        int t2[4];
        int compteur2 = 0;

        for (k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            if (rString[k] == t[k]) //rString is my random string
            {
                t2[compteur2] = k;
                compteur2++;
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
            {
                if (t[y] == rString[j] && y != j) //checking correct letters at wrong positions
                { 
                    compteur++;
                    t[y] = 'z'; //I put this line to avoid counting a letter twice
                }
            }

        if (compteur2 == 4) 
        {
            cout << "bravo\n";
            u = 10;
        } else
        {
            cout << "Positions with correct letters:\n ";
            if (compteur2 == 0)
            {
                cout << "None";
                cout << " ";
            } else
                for (int z = 0; z < compteur2; z++) 
                    c out << t2[z] << ", ";

            cout << " \n";
            cout << "You have a total of " << compteur << " correct letters in wrong positions\n";

        }
        u++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Enter your guess:
 abcd
b, a, b, a,  //note this is my random string I made it print
Positions with correct letters:
 None  
You have a total of 1 correct letters in wrong positions
```

for example here I have 2 correct letters in the wrong position and I am getting 1 as an output

To clarify more about why I put `t[y]='z';` if for example the random string was "accd" and my input was "cxyz" I would get that I have 2 correct letters at wrong positions, so I did that in attempt to fix it.

Any help on how to do this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214735/discussion-on-question-by-doingthisforfun-checking-if-guessed-string-has-a-corre).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(0));

    char lettres[4] = {'a','b','c','d'};
    char rString[4];
    int i = 0;
    //making random string
    while (i < 4) {
        int temp = rand() % 4;
        rString[i] = lettres[temp];
        i++;
    }

    int u = 0;
    char t[4];

    while (u < 10) {
        cout << "Enter your guess:\n ";
        cin >> t;

        //printing random string
        for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
            cout << rString[z] << ", ";
        }
        cout << "\n";

        int correctPositions = 0;
        cout << "Correct Position Are:\n";
        for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
            if (rString[z] == t[z]) {
                cout << (z + 1) << ", ";
                correctPositions++;
            }
        }
        if (correctPositions == 4) {
            cout << "\nBingo!" << "\nThat's Right!";
            return 0;
        }
        if (correctPositions == 0) {
            cout << "None";
        }
        cout << "\n";

        //finding no of correct letters in wrong position:
        int correctLetters = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            char c = lettres[i];
            int randomCount = 0;
            int guessCount = 0;
            int letterInCorrectPos = 0;
            for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
                if (rString[z] == c) {
                    randomCount++;
                }
                if (t[z] == c) {
                    guessCount++;
                }
                if (rString[z] == t[z] && t[z] == c)
                    letterInCorrectPos++;
            }

            correctLetters += min(guessCount, randomCount) - letterInCorrectPos;

        }
        cout << "No. of correct letters but in wrong position :" << correctLetters;
        cout << "\n\n";
        u++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## Explaining Logic

1. Finding No. Of Correct Positions:

This is done by iterating with z = 0 -> z=4 over the `rString` and `t` if `rString[z]` is `t[z]` (the char at z are matching) then we just print the position!

2. Finding No. Of Correct Letters In Wrong Position

This part was little tricky to implement but here is the method I followed.

We have `lettres[]` array which is containing all the letters, right? We will now individual loop over each letter in the array and count the no. of occurrence in the `rString` and `t`, and store the respective counts in a `randomCount` and `guessCount` respectively.

> Ex. let rString = "bdcc" and t = "abcd" so we have the following data:
>
> 'a': randomCount:0 guessCount:1 letterInCorrectPos: 0
>
> 'b': randomCount:1 guessCount:1 letterInCorrectPos: 0
>
> 'c': randomCount:2 guessCount:1 letterInCorrectPos: 1
>
> 'd': randomCount:1 guessCount:1 letterInCorrectPos: 0

This is the first part in the above loop you can see we have another variable `letterInCorrectPos`, this variable stores the no. of instances in the string where, the letter is at the same position in both the strings.

Figuring these three values we can calculate the no. of correct letter:

`correctLetters = min(guessCount, randomCount)`

> the smaller value of guessCount or randomCount is chosen because we don't want repeated counting. (We can't have more correct letters than there are instances of that letter in another class).

Now by simple logic: correct letters in wrong place is (correct letters) - (correct letters in the correct place ).Hence,

`correctLetters = min(guessCount, randomCount) - letterInCorrectPos;`

Since we are iterating in a loop and we want to add correctLetters of each letter, we use this statement at the end of loop:

`correctLetters += min(guessCount, randomCount) - letterInCorrectPos;`

Hope this will explain the working.

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it is supposed to help.

Comment: Yunnosch please tell me what you are not able to understand or not convinced about... PS. I have checked it

Comment: "I have checked it." is actually a useful information, which would improve the answer. My point is however that you have posted a code-only answer. Doing so supports the misunderstanding that StackOverflow is a free programming service. It also does not help askers to actually understand the reasons for the needed change of implementation. Also, though I am sure that I could find the actual change you did and understand it, I simply can more easily do so if the answer also contains a prose explanation. In short, provding an explanation improves code-only answers in many ways, upvotability too.

Comment: You also might consider applying a consistent indentation style. (Not necessarily mine of course... ;-) )